# Random multiple images javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change multiple image random on my website.
This code work only for 1 image.

```
var image = new Array ();
image[0] = "images/pic01.jpg";
image[1] = "images/pic02.jpg";
image[2] = "images/pic03.jpg";
image[3] = "images/pic04.jpg";
image[4] = "images/pic05.jpg";
var size = image.length
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random())

$('#random').attr('src',image[x]);
```

Comment: What do you mean it only works for one image?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? That looks like it should work...

Comment: Well, the code is only changing the `src` of one image. Just do the same for other images?

Comment: if i fill  <img id='random'/> more times in it only work for 1 image

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Still not clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you will need to select multiple elements instead of just one `$('#random')` so use the class selector, not ID. And if you use jQuery, you can use each to iterate through the elements, like so:

```
$('.random').each(function(){
   var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
   $(this).attr('src',image[x]);
});
```

Comment: Or a bit shorter: `$('.random').prop('src', function() { return image[Math.floor(size*Math.random())]; });`

Comment: Please add the html code you are using, but I'm guessing you need to change the html `id="random"` to `class="random"`